# how to download software without fear of viruses?

Tags: virus, software

I've always been afraid of downloading software because of viruses, and that has affected my life as a programmer a lot. So, I want some tips to be able to install and download software without fear of viruses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Well... It depends...

1. You didn't specify your operating system, but the way the question is worded I'm guessing you want software for Windows.
2. You didn't say what software you are looking to download, so I give a few examples for both proprietary software and free/open source software.
3. If you're looking for free downloads of commercial software, that is illegal unless you get a free license from official sources.

### Most important

**On Windows, you NEVER go online or run/install new software without active and updated antivirus.**

### Also important

**Preferably stick to:**

- Official sources
- Trusted sources

**If those aren't available/applicable you could use:**

- Well known, reputable sites with curated content.

But NEVER without using a search engine to check if:

- That site is recommended/criticized by other sites.
- Users have left good/bad reviews somewhere.

Forum threads (if you can find one) usually have back and forth discussion, so they can give a good indicator too.

### P2P / Torrenting

Unless the p2p or torrent link is:

- Posted on an official site.
  **AND**
- File hashes/signatures for verification are available.

Then **stay away**, because there is no way to know/verify what you're downloading.

## Official Sources

- For Windows, MS Office, Visual Studio or other Microsoft products.

  - microsoft.com
  - office.com
- If you need Adobe's Photoshop, Premiere or Creative Suite.

  - adobe.com
- And so on...

## Trusted Sources.

- OS repository/app store.

  - Windows 10 App store etc.
- Online or in-app stores for games.

  - gog.com
  - Steam
  - Origin

**Even TRUSTED sources aren't 100% safe**
Steam offer games/software from many sources, and for them to test every update and release of every title would be impossible.
A few titles that came bundled with very invasive "anti-cheat" functionality, that could potentially take control of a computer did slip through to end users.

### Other curated sources

These **could** be less secure, so do some checking.

Until 2/3 years ago I used the following two sources a lot. With no problems.  (Before I switched to Linux)

- ninite.com
- chocolatey

Great for automatically and easily downloading and installing/updating software.

There are loads of alternatives now, but I have no experience with those.

## Other OSes

- Mac OS X
- GNU/Linux
- BSD
- etc...

All these come with their own built in software management tools in different flavors. Like App stores and/or package managers.

They are usually **very safe**. Stick to them when ever possible.

Comment: I would not cite Steam as a trusted source, because there have been instances of developers inserting kernel-level rootkits into their games for "Anti-Cheat purposes". So while Steam is indeed reputable, it doesn't make it malware free

Comment: @MechMK1 I'm open to suggestions and I'll gladly correct my error if you tell me how you think it should be. Thanks.

Comment: @MechMK1 Steam is not statistically unsafe if you look at the numbers...

Comment: I agree that *most* of the software is likely fine - but I would add a note that even reputable platforms like steam can contain malware

Comment: @MechMK1 Something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You could

1. Use a virus scanner
2. Download from reputable sites
3. See how popular a tool is, if it’s fairly well-known it’s less likely to suddenly be infected

In the end there’s no guarantee though, there could always be a new virus out there that suddenly made it in some software.